# Безопасное хранение данных в LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, localstorage

Я храню данные пользователя в localStorage и через Vuex получаю их.
У меня там есть параметр, что пользователь является админом.

Если злой пользователь нажмет F12 и в консоли изменит значение, то он получит доступ к админке.
Как этого избежать?

Client Side Rendering.
Если это поможет. У меня авторизация через JWT токен и refresh токен.

Comment: Храните зашифрованный токен, который будет отправляться вместе с каждым запросом на сервер. На сервере проверка: если токен валидный, значит разрешаем пользователю определенное действие, если нет - не разрешаем.

Comment: Токен авторизации у админа и пользователя делается по одному принципу.
А вот имя пользователя и является ли он админом отправляется отдельно вместе с токеном на frontend.

интерфейс имеет client side rendering. Вопрос стоит в безопасности роутинга в админку.
Я же не могу это проверить через сервер?
Могу лишь проверить, когда пользователь пытается уже что-то там изменить.

Comment: По поводу апдейта. Если вопрос касается исключительно проверки на "админ/не админ", то решение, в принципе, нормальное, если речь идет о запрете нажатия каких-то кнопок, посещения определенных роутов и т.п. Только не забывайте, что на сервере тоже **обязательно** должна быть проверка.

Comment: Из разряда, что действительно кто-то руками записал в LS, что он админ, у него появился доступ к роуту /admin, он может нажать на кнопку "удалить товар", но при этом товар на самом деле не удалится, потому что сервер распознает, что пользователь на самом деле администратором не является. Короче, основные "ворота" безопасности так или иначе должны быть не сервере. Не на клиенте.

Comment: Такую информацию логичнее хранить в самом токене

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Флаг является ли пользователь админом, должен быть частью JWT токена.

А это значит, что подписывается он на сервере, используя пароль известный только серверу. Так что изменить его пользователю не удастся. Можно только украсть его у другого пользователя.

Да, пользователь может изменить что-то локально, чтоб у него показывались какие-то элементы UI доступные только администратору, но любые операции будь-то чтение чувствительных данных или модификации, должны происходить с контролем токена на сервере. А токен, как мы установили, пользователь не может подделать.